# Laravel password reset mail not sending

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, swiftmailer

When using the default `password/reset` route in Laravel and inputting a valid email address that's in my users table, I get the following error:

```
Class 'Swift_Mime_Headers_DateHeader' not found

…/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleHeaderFactory.php:80
```

If I look in the inspector, I see the following form data:

```
_token: 09Lgy2iFIkYgmg6HGgDnJIQiM31jnP3WrM4bBsnh
email: testresetemail@hotmail.com
```

So it seems that everything should work as expected. What does this error mean and how can I make the password reset mail work?

Comment: What version of `swiftmailer` is in use ? You could get it from here, http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/source-class-Swift_Mime_Headers_DateHeader.html#11-113 But it may be a sign of larger problem.

Comment: I use the one that came default with Laravel, in the changelog it says it's version 6.0.2

Comment: take a look in the swiftmailer folder for the `DateHeader.php.php` file, it may be missing. This should be where `Swift_Mime_Headers_DateHeader ` is defined. Is this the only error ?

Comment: I have a file `DateHeader.php` in `\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Mime\Headers\` and it starts with  `class Swift_Mime_Headers_DateHeader extends Swift_Mime_Headers_AbstractHeader`

Comment: Have you tried running a `composer install` or `composer update`? Sounds like you're missing dependencies

Comment: I've run composer install and composer update, but I get the same results. It doesn't mention swiftmailer in the output, so I think it didn't update it

Comment: Could you add your `composer.lock` file using https://pastebin.com/?

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/aJWwFLQ9